# Как задать фон нажатой кнопке?

Tags: html, css, button

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] - не нажата.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] - нажата.

Нужно поменять фон нажатой кнопки (CSS). Псевдо класс `:visited` не работает

```
<div class="btngroup2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btngroup2__btnmyset">Visit Website</button>
</div>

.btngroup2__btnmyset {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    background: none;
    width: 150px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
    height: 40px;
}

.btngroup2__btnmyset:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btngroup2__btnmyset:hover {
    outline: none;
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    color: rgb(255, 193, 55);
    border-color: rgb(255, 193, 55);
    width: 180px;
}
```

P.S. Использую bootstrap.

Comment: Зажата или нажата?

Comment: Тут уже правильно подсказали, нужно использовать :active, да и в дальнейшем придерживаться мнемоники "love-hate". Но вот именно у Bootstrap'а псевдокласс :active переопределяется в комбинации с :hover и :focus. В итоге и не получается так просто его использовать. Рекомендую исследовать код через F12 в браузере. Там будет показано, какое правило в бутстрапе мешает.

Comment: @Yuri нажата. Вообщем я решил проблему просто заменив все кнопки на ссылки с таким же оформлением как и было придерживаясь мнемоники "love-hate" с ссылками сработало а кнопками также проблемы. У меня теперь новая проблема оформление спадает при добавление hrefу mailto: и тоже кажется из за бутстрапа все слетает.

Comment: Насколько мне известно бутстрап не влияет на оформление при использовании атрибутов href у ссылок. Вероятно проблема в оформлении псевдокласса :link. Дело в том, что он действует только в случае, когда у тэга A есть атрибут href, т.е. когда якорь превращается в ссылку.

Comment: @ОлегСолдатов, псевдоэлемент :link я вообще не стилизовал только :hover :focus :visited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно использовать псевдокласс `:active`

Comment: тоже пробовал не работает во всех местах и перед и после :hover

Comment: @СеверинВладислав, погугли принцип love-hate и поставь селекторы в правильном порядке.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я специально написал что во всех местах пробовал чтоб мне таких ответов не писали....

Answer (score 0):

вот вам то что вы хотели...

```
.btngroup2__btnmyset {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 1em;
    outline: none;
    border-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    background:rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    width: 150px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
    height: 40px;

}
.btngroup2__btnmyset:hover {
   margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 1em;
    outline: none;
    border-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    background:rgba(1, 251, 1, 1);
    width: 150px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
    height: 40px;
}
.btngroup2__btnmyset:active{
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    background:rgba(251, 251, 251, 1);
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;

}
```